# A non well formed numeric value encountered while using fmod

Tags: php

I am new in php
I am using fomd function.

```
if ($time_long > 8){
        $z=8;
        $q= fmod($time_long,$z);
        $x2=$q;
```

I getting modulus fine but with a notice saying 
A non well formed numeric value encountered
any suggerstion

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear, isn't it? So how _are_ your arguments formed? Probably not float values...

Comment: What does `$time_long` look like? My guess is that `var_dump($time_long);` would return a string, rather than an integer. So when you call `fmod($time_long,$z)`, php first has to convert your string value into an int (or float) before returning the floating point remainder (modulo)

Answer (score 0):

In your code every thing looks perfect. So problem is with `$time_long` variable. Probably it will passing an String value to the `if` function.

Read [fmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function as well.

So you to check that, use

```
print_r($time_long);
die();
```

This will print the content of variable.

so it would be come as

```
$time_long = 15//integer value

if ($time_long > 8){
    $z=8;
    $q= fmod($time_long,$z);
    $x2=$q;
```